# Android Animation - translate viewgroup, children not translating from the same place

Tags: android, animation, delay, translate, viewgroup

I am simply translating a cardview that contains an image and textview, horizontally from outside the screen, to inside.

[image: daily calls]

here is my animation xml which is referenced using android:layoutAnimation of the cardview xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-300"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

I want the card to maintain its look and animate as a whole from one point to another, but instead I get a weird delay between the card and its contained views making for an ugly animation, the below image is my best attempt to describe it visually:

[image: daily calls anim]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have done like this

```
    ObjectAnimator settleAnimator;
if(settleAnimator==null){
            settleAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourView, "translationX", 0);
        settleAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                inAnimation = true;//just a boolean
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                inAnimation = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                inAnimation = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });

}
      settleAnimator.setDuration(200);//millisec

//this will take start value and end value in pixels ie. (from, to)
        settleAnimator.setFloatValues(+300, 0);
        settleAnimator.start();

}
```

Comment: This is essentially doing the same thing but programatically, thanks for your input though. I have found my problem, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that while I was testing different ways of doing this I left both the programmatic code and the xml code in, thus causing strange doubled up animations.